# AWS ECS Blue Green Deployments - CloudFormation Error

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

Trying to execute a blue/green deployment of an ECS task within AWS using the CloudFormation approach (as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html) and the deployment fails.

The initial stack deployment works fine and the ECS task is deployed and running as expected with the correct load balancer and target group etc. However when updating the task definition, to trigger a blue/green deployment, it fails with the message:

```
Imports and exports are currently not supported on templates using hooks
```

The deployment is created in CodeDeploy, so it's obviously triggered as expected, but the deployment screen in AWS console shows the following error:

```
The deployment failed because the stack update that triggered this CodeDeploy deployment failed in CloudFormation. In the AWS CloudFormation console, go to the Events tab to view status and error messages.
```

But the puzzling thing is the CloudFormation template does not appear to contain any imports or exports.  I have even tried copying the yml from the documented example and it doesn't work.

I'm executing the CloudFormation updates using Serverless Framework, but I don't think that's an issue, the error is logged in the CloudFormation stack events tab.

Probably not unreasonable to expect the example in the AWS documentation to work?

Answer (score 1):

So we did find the cause of this issue, and in fact the problem was actually caused by running the CloudFormation template via the serverless framework.

The serverless approach works for all our other AWS deployments, but the CodeDeploy transform explicitly requires for there to be no outputs from the CF template - however serverless actually adds the name of the S3 bucket that it uses as an output, which breaks this particular use case.

Therefore the solution was to invoke the CF template directly from the AWS CLI and it works perfectly.